# Navigating between JFrames and JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to do a simple application with 'Login' and 'User home'
[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqCl8.png)

[User Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdUFM.png)

I tried using GUI designer in Netbeans.
I need to load different contents like: say,

- User bio-data,
- Travel details, blah blah as different pages/frames into the 'content page'
  based on the options selected on the side menu.

I tried like this via `JPanel` containers to switch between pages:

```
    FirstPanel first = new FirstPanel();
    contentPanel.removeAll();
    contentPanel.add(first);
    first.setVisible(true);
    contentPanel.revalidate();
    contentPanel.repaint();
```

Also I need to load data from DB along with the view switching :(
Am I doing it correct or is it unconventional to do this way?

Also how to switch between the `JFrame` windows ( n a way user doesn't understood that Frame has changed)

Comment: `contentPanel.removeAll();` 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) Choose tags carefully for best attention & help. This has everything to do with Java & nothing to do with the IDE.

Comment: Using a GUI  designer is a harmful idea.  Coding the GUI by hand will help you better learn Swing.  Use one JFrame and multiple JPanels.  A JDialog is useful for a login page.  The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is a good way to learn Swing.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for the update :) Being new to SWING, I found GUI builder easy  :) But found it hard to solve coz all the solutions found on here are Coding by ourselves